# Why is my list different than what I appended?

Tags: python

I am working on a project that makes an 'ai' for a game called hexapawn that works via removing the possibility of a move occurring at that board position if the player ends up winning right after. For some that I am unaware of, whenever I append my board position and move that was made, when I print the whole list at the end, everything is right except the board inside each entry in the list.

Note: If I append the move entry as a string, everything works. But I need to have it be a list so that I can index from it later.

I know this has something to do with multiple references to the same list but I don't see where it's happening.

Here is my code.

```
import random

def main():
    print(printBoard(board))
    move(0, 0, board)
    print(printBoard(board))
    move(2, 1, board)
    print(printBoard(board))
    print(f'What I have in the end: {moves_ai}')

board = [
    [1, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [2, 2, 2]
    ]

moves_ai = []

forbiden_moves_ai = []

#Board Mechanics
def printBoard(board):
    return str(board[0]) + '\n' + str(board[1]) + '\n' + str(board[2]) + '\n'

def move(row, col, board):
    if board[row][col] == 1:
        if board[row + 1][col] == 0:
            moves_ai.append([row, col, row + 1, col, board])
            print(f'What I appended: {[row, col, row + 1, col, board]}')
            board[row + 1][col] = 1
            board[row][col] = 0
        else:
            return -1
    if board[row][col] == 2:
        if board[row - 1][col] == 0:
            moves_ai.append([row, col, row - 1, col, board])
            print(f'What I appended: {[row, col, row - 1, col, board]}')
            board[row - 1][col] = 2
            board[row][col] = 0
        else:
            return -1

def is_possible(end_row, end_col, board):
    if end_row < 0 or end_row > 2 or end_col < 0 or end_col > 2:
        return False
        
    return True

#AI Section
def random_move(board):
    ind = []
    move_decided = False
    for row in range(3):
        for col in range(3):
            if board[row][col] == 2:
                ind.append([row, col])
    while not move_decided:
        r_move = random.choice(ind)
        if bool(random.getrandbits(1)):
            if [r_move[0], r_move[1], r_move[0] - 1, r_move[1], board] not in forbiden_moves_ai and move(r_move[0], r_move[1], board) != -1:       
                move_decided = True
            else:
                continue
        else:
            left = bool(random.getrandbits(1))
            if left:
                if [r_move[0], r_move[1], r_move[0] - 1, r_move[1] - 1, board] not in forbiden_moves_ai:
                    if capture(left, r_move[0], r_move[1], board) != -1:
                        move_decided = True
                    else:
                        continue
            else:
                if [r_move[0], r_move[1], r_move[0] - 1, r_move[1] + 1, board] not in forbiden_moves_ai:
                    if capture(left, r_move[0], r_move[1], board) != -1:
                        move_decided = True
                    else:
                        continue
    

def remove_move(row1, col1, row2, col2, situation):
    forbiden_moves_ai.append([row1, col1, row2, col2, situation])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is the expected output:

```
What I have in the end: [[0, 0, 1, 0, [[1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0], [2, 2, 2]]], [2, 1, 1, 1, [[0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], [2, 2, 2]]]]
```

This is the output:

```
What I have in the end: [[0, 0, 1, 0, [[0, 1, 1], [1, 2, 0], [2, 0, 2]]], [2, 1, 1, 1, [[0, 1, 1], [1, 2, 0], [2, 0, 2]]]]
```

Also, here is an easy way to recreate the problem:

```
l = []
num = [1]

l.append(num)
num[0] = 9
l.append(num)

print(l)
```

Expected result:

```
[[1], [9]]
```

Result:

```
[[9], [9]]
```

I am still keeping the full code I wrote so that anyone who used that can still copy and paste it again.

Comment: Hello. Which list are you referring to? Can you print out the contents of the list and how they differ from what you expected? Please [edit] your question to include these things. Also, if it makes sense please provide a [mcve] -- remove as much unrelated code as possible.

Comment: Also, JFYI, you're appending to `moves_ai`, but printing `board`.

Comment: If it works when you stringify but don't when you keep the lists, I would suspect you are facing problems regarding Mutability. Appending items to a list is a mutable operation, hence, the state of an object can be changed from outside of the list.

Comment: @joseville Yes, I know that it is intentional. I did it to track the board after each move function call. It is sort of like a game, but thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @ItagybaAbondanzaKuhlmann I don't really understand what you mean by that. Could you give an example, please?

Comment: @AbhijitPrajapati, I've made an example in [this notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1rPeoTPmm6JDIC0UAwD09mepFl-nY13se?usp=sharing)

Comment: @AbhijitPrajapati, thanks for adding the smaller example. It really is easier to diagnose issues with smaller examples and you are more likely to get answers. Please also add your actual and expected output when using the smaller exmample.

Comment: @joseville I was able to reduce the problem a bit more, therefore I added a more minimalistic way to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @AbhijitPrajapati, I see that. With the reduced problem, we still need to know your actual and expected outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
l = []
num = [1]

l.append(num)
print(l) # [[1]]
num[0] = 9
print(l) # [[9]]
l.append(num)

print(l)
```

The issue is as @Itagyba Abondanza Kuhlmann stated. `num` is mutable. When you append it to `l`, you're not appending a snapshot of `num`, you're appending a "reference" to `num`. In the end, `l` contains as its elements two references, both to `num` which equals `[9]` which is why you `l` is `[[9], [9]]`.

[pythontutor.com](https://www.pythontutor.com) might help you see what is going on behind the scenes. Also, this presentation by Ned Batchelder explains some of this in a very good way: [presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AEJHKGk9ns).